# While true loop function

Tags: c++, c, while-loop

To my understanding, a while loop can be done this way :

```
while (true) {
    // run this code
    if (condition satisfies)
        break; // return;
}
```

So I took it and I put in the following main function below, my problem is that when I put a printf statement after I meet the condition ( 5 or more ), it stops and doesn't display anything, and if I put nothing but the break statement it works and it loops through 5 different customers! am I missing anything about the while true loop or is this the way it works ?

```
int main ()
{
    displayMenu();
    while (true)
    {
        int gasType,gallonsAmount,carWashOption,customerAmount ;
        float gasPrices[SIZE]={2.99,3.099,3.199,3.299}, washPrices[SIZE]=
        {3.50,3.00,3.00,2.50}, perGallonRate,perWashRate,total;
        float totalSum,totalGallonSum;
        gasType = getGasType();
        gallonsAmount = getGallons();
        carWashOption = getCarWash();
        perGallonRate = getGallonRate(gasPrices, gasType);
        if (carWashOption == 'Y')
        {
            perWashRate = getWashRate( washPrices, gasType );
            total = calcAmount(gallonsAmount, perGallonRate, perWashRate,&totalSum, &totalGallonSum);
        }
        else 
        {
            perWashRate = 0;
            total = calcAmount(gallonsAmount, perGallonRate, perWashRate,&totalSum, &totalGallonSum);
        }
        customerAmount++;// once we reach a total of 5 customers(Assume its the end of the day), the loop will break and give me a summary.
        if (customerAmount >= 5)
            printf("totalSum: %.2f ", totalSum ,totalGallonSum);
            break;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C or C++ ? You must choose one language.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the curly braces around the printf and break statement. Now it will break at the first run of the loop.

Comment: FWIW, your mistake is almost exactly the same as the `goto fail;` bug that Apple had in their TLS implementation a few years ago. Compare e.g. https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html and https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 if (customerAmount >= 5)
    printf("totalSum: %.2f ", totalSum , totalGallonSum  );
    break;
```

`break` is not part of `if`.So the very first time your loop ends.
Use braces.

```
 if (customerAmount >= 5)
 {
    printf("totalSum: %.2f ", totalSum , totalGallonSum  );
    break;
  }
```

Comment: gcc now reports a "suspicious indentation" in those cases BTW.

Comment: Sorry, I a little broken you answer by formatting OP code ^^'. By the way, The OP didn't initialize `customerAmount`. Maybe you should add that put his counter outside the `while` and put the condition inside this while would be better ? `while (customerAmount < 5)`.

Comment: Thank you, you are a real hero! I always put brackets but for some reason my brain did not function right for me to put the bracket and thought I did not have to.. thats after trying many other solutions. @Stargateur i know how that works as well but I HAVE to use a while true loop.

Comment: @AliSoujod Well, if you want but your code invoke undefined behavior don't expect that it's will work all time.